# How to refresh data in PyQt TableWidget?

Tags: python, sqlite, pyqt

For example, I have a SQLite database and I grab data from this database and put it into `QTableWidget`. But then, I make some stuff with this data.

So, how can I update data in this table without `setItem` method?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please have a little bit more detailed information in the content with your effort to solve the problem?

Comment: @manetsus, I have integers in a column, I've subtracted from them 1, now I need to refresh my table, to have new values.

Comment: @OleksandrIvanenko I think what manetsus meant was that you should [edit] your question to include more detail; that is better than adding a comment below.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`QTableView`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html) instead, where you can dynamically change the data in the underlying model (e.g. a [`QStandardItemModel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditemmodel.html)). In your case, you might even be able to simply use a [`QSqlQueryModel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquerymodel.html) or [`QSqlTableModel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqltablemodel.html) with your database.